# Dagger 2: Injecting member which has constructor parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependencies, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to learn Dagger 2 by implementing a dummy Java console application and I have this class.

```
public class Lemonader {

    private Water water;
    private Lemon lemon;
    private Sugar sugar;

    private WaterCooler waterCooler;

    public Lemonader(Water water, Lemon lemon, Sugar sugar) {
        this.water = water;
        this.lemon = lemon;
        this.sugar = sugar;
        this.waterCooler = new WaterCooler(water); // TODO remove hard dependency via Dagger 2
    }

    public void makeLemonade() {
        System.out.println("Making lemonade..");
        waterCooler.coolItUpTheWater();
        System.out.println("Lemonade has been made with " + water.getAmount() + " liters of water, " + sugar.getAmount() + " kilograms of sugar and " + lemon.getQuantity() + " lemons.");
    }
```

And this is how i create the `Lemonader` object

```
public class LemonaderHelper {

    public Lemonader getLemonader(int waterAmount, boolean isWaterHot, int lemonQuantity, int sugarAmount) {
        Water w = new Water(); 
        w.setAmount(waterAmount);
        w.setCold(isWaterHot);

        Lemon l = new Lemon(); 
        l.setQuantity(lemonQuantity);

        Sugar s = new Sugar(); 
        s.setAmount(sugarAmount);

        Lemonader lemonader = new Lemonader(w, l, s); 

        return lemonader;
    }

}
```

I want to inject the `WaterCooler` member of Lemonader via Dagger 2 but i could not find a way to pass `water` instance that comes from `Lemonader` constructor(I tried creating modules that provide `Water` and `WaterCooler`. It worked but it is creating a new `water` instace instead of passing the one which comes from `Lemonader` constructor). How can i do this via Dagger 2 ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Dagger 2 is meant for the automatic provision of dependencies in the graph. Because WaterCooler only takes one dependency and it isn't in the graph, making the use of WaterCooler an implementation detail, I'd have it exactly as you do:

```
this.waterCooler = new WaterCooler(water);
```

However, if you wanted to be able to substitute implementations, you might think about injecting a *related object* which has one method that takes one parameter (water) and returns a source of cool water. You might think of this as just a constructor wrapper, but it's actually following the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

```
interface SourceOfCoolWaterFactory {
  /** Probably returns a water cooler. Might return a refrigerator. */
  SourceOfCoolWater createCoolWaterSource(Water water);
}
```

Ah ha! Now you can inject `SourceOfCoolWaterFactory`, and create an implementation that simply calls `new WaterCooler(water)`. This removes the hard dependency you identify in your code comment, allowing you to substitute any implementation you want—including mocks for tests. Importantly, this also allows you to *mix in dependencies from your graph*, such as when your WaterCooler runs out of batteries:

```
public class WaterCoolerFactory implements {
  private final Provider<Electricity> electricityProvider;

  @Inject public WaterCoolerFactory(Provider<Electricity> electricityProvider) {
    this.electricityProvider = electricityProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public SourceOfCoolWater createCoolWaterSource(Water water) { 
    return new WaterCooler(water, electricityProvider.get());
  }
}
```

You now have an implementation you can bind in Dagger, allowing your Lemonader to inject a SourceOfCoolWaterFactory instead of calling the WaterCooler constructor directly, and correctly adding the graph-produced dependencies like `Electricity` to your constructor dependencies like `Water`.

---

Though Dagger doesn't actually provide any way to automate factories, Google has a sister project called [AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory), which can generate injectable factories for any [JSR-330](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) dependency injection framework (e.g. Dagger, Guice, and Spring), and which sits among code generators for value objects and Java services, in a package called [Google Auto](https://github.com/google/auto). With AutoFactory, you can annotate WaterCooler with a few annotations, AutoFactory will create an implementation you can bind in Dagger:

```
// If you don't specify a class to implement, Dagger will write one.
// This might be useful if you only have one implementation, but you
// want to substitute it with a mock in tests.
@AutoFactory(implementing = SourceOfCoolWaterFactory.class)
public WaterCooler(Water water, @Provided Electricity electricity) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have been reading about DI and DI frameworks for a while and i found the terms newable and injectable. Looks like my Water class is a newable and i should not be injecting it via DI framework instead i should remove it from injectable's constructor and create it via new operator. so looks like i have some problems with my app design which i have to fix before applying Dagger 2 as a DI framework.

Comment: @Tartar Don't worry too much about snapping your fingers and making every binding perfectly substitutable; software design is often too messy for that. Dagger can give you an automated way to wire things up as they evolve and as you need to gain flexibility in your object creation, and in that sense you can be pragmatic and add bindings slowly starting with the most obvious and valuable bindings.